# Spring mvc bind errors internatiolization

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have some issue with resolving typeMismatch Exceptions on binding. Type mismatch errors don't resolving from my messages.properties.

My controller handler:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
    ValidationResponse addOrder(@ModelAttribute(value = PARAM_NAME) @Valid Orders orders, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
}
```

I getting this messages from bindingResult.

Spring config:

```
...
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean name="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="messageSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
...
```

`/WEB-INF/messages.properties`:

```
...
Orders.width.NotNull=Null error
Orders.height.NotNull=Null error
typeMismatch.java.util.Date=Format error
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer=Format error
typeMismatch.java.lang.Long=Format error
java.lang.NumberFormatException=Format error
typeMismatch.java.lang.NumberFormatException=Format error
typeMismatch.java.lang.NumberFormat=Format error
typeMismatch.orderAdd.width=Format error
typeMismatch=Format error
...
```

For checks like this one:

```
...
@NotNull(message="{Orders.width.NotNull}")
private Long width;
...
```

I got correct messages.

**UPDATE**

This example prints error messages:

```
List<FieldError> allErrors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
  for (FieldError objectError : allErrors) {
    System.out.println(objectError.getDefaultMessage());
}
```

Comment: How does the message appear (for the one that is not working)?

Comment: Yes, tbh I didn't understand what's working and what's not(or working not as expected) in this question

Comment: @Rachel G., i've updated question

Comment: In your update, what does "prints error messages" means? What do the messages say?

Comment: @Rachel G., this is only example. In real code this list with some modifications sends as JSON to JavaScript.

Comment: @Rachel G., for example, in case of null `width` field, it contains something like `Null error` (see messages.properties). It's ok. But in case of NumberFormatException it contains: 'Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long' for property 'width'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "as"'. So, this string doesn't from my messages.properties, and i don't know why.

Comment: And `orderAdd` is the name of your command, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202437/spring-how-to-resolve-a-validation-error-error-code-error-message) question. To translate message, i have to inject `messageSource` and use the following code:

```
messageSource.getMessage(objectError, locale)
```

This gets message from my properties file.